# Increment and decrement RethinkDB Single Value

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

**RethinkDB** Increment and Decrement Single Value

Need some help, I'm learning Nodejs and Rethinkdb.

Currently I'm using this RethinkDB code to perform the Update operation.

```
r.table('items').get(id).update(item).run(self.connection, function(err, result) {
    if(result && result.replaced === 1) {
        res.send(item);
    }
    else if(err) {
        debug("[ERROR] updateItem %s:%s\n%s", err.name, err.msg, err.message);
        res.send({error: 'An error occurred when updating the item with id: ' + id});
    }
    else {
        debug("[ERROR] updateItem (%s): %j", id, result);
        res.send({error: 'An error occurred when updating the item with id: ' + id});
    }
});
```

Now the question is: How can i update a value in a row by Incrementing its value? For example lets say its about the stock of a car. so in a row i'll have:

```
    {
    "code":  "001" ,
    "brand":  "Ferrari" ,
    "stock":  "2"
    }
```

Now lets say I make a form to control how many cars will be added or removed from the stock. So for example let's say I want to add 3 new Ferraris. How can i update the value **stock**, incrementing the stock by 3 for a total of 5 and not replacing 2 for 3. Also lets say I sold 2 Ferraris, how can I decrease the value so the stock value will be 0.

And please excuse my poor English. Not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here's what you can do. To add, use something like this:

```
r.table("items").get(id).update({
    stock: r.row("stock").add(2)
}).run(self.connection, callback);
```

To substract:

```
r.table("items").get(id).update({
    stock: r.row("stock").sub(3)
}).run(self.connection, callback);
```

**Update**

So, the values in the database are actually strings. You need to coerce them first. This should work:

```
r.table("items").get(id).update({
    stock: r.row("stock").coerceTo("number").add(2).coerceTo("string")
}).run(self.connection, callback);
```

Comment: First Thanks. But when I try the code, it just add 2 next to the original value, so instead of 2 + 2 = 4, I got: 22

Comment: So, the value you have in the database is a string, not int. Sorry, didn't notice that. You want it this way? Maybe just convert it using `parseInt`.

Comment: `parseInt` won't work, in fact, but I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!! Works great.